# How to replace variable content on click?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, hyperlink

I have an array

```
var oldVar = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

The array is used by some function.

```
function myFunction() {
 // Do stuff with oldVar.
}
```

I would like to replace oldVar content by content of another variable

```
var newVar = ["d", "e",  "f"];
```

After clicking on a link. I tried something like:

```
<a onclick="changeVar()">Change</a>

function changeVar() {
 oldVar = newVar;
}
```

But if I click on a link and then call myFunction() by separate button, it still uses [“a”, “b”, c]. How to make it use [“d”, “e”,  f”]?

I made a working example [here](https://codepen.io/radekjohn/pen/BJWPMp). I would like the oldVar to be ["d", "e",  "f"], when I click on the "Change" button. I am sorry it took me so long. I was busy during the day.

I have a solution, but it is cumbersome. It is [here](https://codepen.io/radekjohn/pen/vpLjmq).

Comment: Can you make a working example that shows the issue?

Comment: Is the array declared inside this function? If so, try declaring the array outside all functions , that way making it global. Please post a bigger example of your code.

Comment: Javascript variables get passed by reference for the record, but I think your issue might be scope. Javascript uses function scope rather than block scope. Are you declaring oldVar globally, or within the chageVar funciton?

Comment: `“a”` invalid quotes.

Comment: @epascarello I can try.

Comment: @Ivan86 and Abid Hasan: Both oldVar and newVar are declared outside. But this is just my simplified example for the sake of the question.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan True. it is just in this example. I am switching between English and exotic eastern-European keyboard.

Comment: @epascarello I added the working (OK, not working) example to the last paragraph. I am sorry that it took me so long. I was busy whole day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the length to zero and use push for inserting the items to the `oldVar`.

```js
function changeVar() {
    oldVar.length = 0;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(oldVar, newVar);
    show();
}

function show() {
    console.log(oldVar);
}

var oldVar = ["a", "b", "c"],
    newVar = ["d", "e", "f"];
```

```html
<a onclick="changeVar()">Change</a>
```